# Django V2.1 reverse is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Django and I have created two apps in my project one is **login** & **server_status**. I have used the namespace method to access my login and server_status across both apps. It is working fine when I tried to access index but when I tried to access `dashboard` in `server_status` it is not working.

```
Reverse for 'server_status' not found. 'server_status' is not a valid view function or pattern name

# server_status URL

from django.urls import path
from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
path('', include('server_status.urls', namespace='server_status')),
path('', include('login.urls', namespace='login')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

# login app URL

app_name = 'login'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.index, name='index')
]


# project URL

    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import include, path

    app_name = 'server_status'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('server_status/', views.server_status, name='server_status'),
    path('request_access/', views.request_access, name='request_access'),
]
```

In **server_status/templates/server_status/index.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'server_status:dashboard' %}" class="button primary centered-s">Login</a>
```

I know this is very simple one, but it makes me very complicated.

Comment: `login:login` should read `login:index`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @ggdx yes I tried login:index too, but the result is negative

Comment: You are currently not using namespaces in your urlpatterns. It should be just `index` - but then it collides with the one in the main patterns.

Comment: @petr Now I changed `server_statuer` **index** as **home** and keep `login` url as '' now it is working but is that correct way do that? `<a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="button primary centered-s">Login</a>`

Comment: @petr the login URL should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/login. what I need to do if I need to keep this as my login page URL?

Answer (score 2):

In the posted code, you define `urlpatterns` twice, so the first set of `urlpatterns` is overridden by the second. Since `server_status` is defined in the first set, it is not present in memory, since you obliterate it in the second definition. `index` is the only pattern that survives. I think what you meant to do in the second stanza was to *add* to the urlpatterns with:

`urlpatterns += [...]`

Comment: Aside: All of your imports should live at the top of the module - there is no reason to bring them in lower down.

Comment: Hi, @shacker thanks for your comments the issue was resolved. I have forgotten to change the URL inside the dashboard.html my apologies to everyone for that.

Comment: OK... but my answer is still correct - you are redefining `urlpatterns` and you'll have to fix that if you want your app to work!

Comment: For example: `a = 1; a = 2; print(a)`  This prints 2, not 1,2 and not 3. You want to *combine* urlpatterns, not override them!

Answer (score 0):

To declare namespace you should do something like this:

```
# project URL

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('server_status.urls', namespace='server_status')),
    path('', include('login.urls', namespace='login')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

then you can use

```
<a href="{% url 'login:index' %}" class="button primary centered-s">Login</a>
```

or

```
<a href="{% url 'server_status:index' %}" class="button primary centered-s">Server status index</a>
```

Comment: It's working fine for index method but for dashboard it is not working but I did the same thing for all.

Comment: I have updated my question could you please check that once?